# Copying a realm-file seems to cause realm Migration-block call - why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

After copying a .realm-file from folder-location1 to folder-location2 (and also changing its name from location1.realm to location2.realm using NSFileManager) - it seems that after doing so, the first call to this new file causes a migration-block call! (i.e. setSchemaVersion). I wonder WHY ???

Prior calls to the "location1/location1.realm" File did not cause a migration-block call - however calls to "location2/location2.realm" do - and the files are identical in structure (at least in Realm-Browser there is no obvious difference) !!

Here is my code :

```
    ApplicatonSuppPathHandler *ApplicationSupportPathHandler = [[ApplicatonSuppPathHandler alloc] init];

    // creation of location where this directory shall be placed on the iPhone
    // typically /library/Application Support/<bundleID_name>/RLMGeneralDatabasesFolderName/...
    // = name of directory that the .realm-File finally should be placed in
    NSString *RLMLocation1DirectoryName = folderName;

    // if it does not exist already, create the RLMLocation_xyz-directory (.../library/Application Support/<bundleID_name>/RLMDatabasesFolderName)
    if([ApplicationSupportPathHandler getURLToApplicationDirectoryWithSubDirectory:RLMLocation1DirectoryName] == nil) {
        [ApplicationSupportPathHandler createSubDirectoryAtLocationToApplicationDirectory:RLMLocation1DirectoryName];
    }

    // get the name of entire directory just created
    NSURL *RLMLocation1Directory = [ApplicationSupportPathHandler getURLToApplicationDirectoryWithSubDirectory:RLMLocation1DirectoryName];

    // name of entire path-name (including filename !! ...needed for copy function below...)
    NSString *RLMLocation1Path = [[RLMLocation1Directory path]  stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    // HERE IS WHERE THE MIGRATION BLOCK IS CALLED - WHY ?????
    // *******************************************************
    RLMRealm *realm_Location1 = [RLMRealm realmWithPath:RLMLocation1Path]; // pointing to realm file at path


    // the rest does work after the migration-block call...
    [realm_Location1 beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm_Location1 deleteAllObjects]; 
    [realm_Location1 addObject:RLMTopoRes];
    [realm_Location1 commitWriteTransaction];
```

Below is the implementation of the used ApplicationSuppPathHandler class-methods:

```
@implementation ApplicatonSuppPathHandler

- (NSURL*)getURLToApplicationDirectoryWithSubDirectory:(NSString*)SubDirectoryName {

NSString* appBundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
NSFileManager*fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL* dirPath = nil;

// Find the application support directory in the home directory.
NSArray* appSupportDir = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                    inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
if ([appSupportDir count] > 0)
{
    // Append the bundle ID and the location-Foldername to the URL for the Application Support directory
    dirPath = [[[appSupportDir objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:appBundleID] URLByAppendingPathComponent:SubDirectoryName];

    BOOL isDir;
    BOOL exists = [fm fileExistsAtPath:[dirPath path] isDirectory:&isDir];
    if (exists) {
        /* file exists */
        if (isDir) {
            /* path exists */
            return dirPath;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Directory does not exist");
            return nil;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* file does not exist */
        return nil;
    }
}
return dirPath;
}

- (void)createSubDirectoryAtLocationToApplicationDirectory:(NSString*)SubDirectoryName {

NSString* appBundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
NSFileManager*fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL* dirPath = nil;

// Find the application support directory in the home directory.
NSArray* appSupportDir = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                    inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
if ([appSupportDir count] > 0)
{
    // Append the bundle ID and the location-Foldername to the URL for the Application Support directory
    dirPath = [[[appSupportDir objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:appBundleID] URLByAppendingPathComponent:SubDirectoryName];

    // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
    // This method call works in OS X 10.7 and later only.
    NSError* theError = nil;
    if (![fm createDirectoryAtURL:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&theError]) {
        // Handle the error.
        NSLog(@"%@", theError.localizedDescription);
    }
    else {
        // Mark the directory as excluded from iCloud backups
        if (![dirPath setResourceValue:@YES
                                forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                                 error:&theError]) {
            NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from iCloud backup %@", [dirPath lastPathComponent], theError.localizedDescription);
        }
        else {
            // NSLog(@"Location Directory excluded from iClud backups");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was previously a bug in Realm where new realm files would have their schema version set to 0 instead of the current schema version, which would trigger a migration in your case.

A fix for this was pushed to the `master` branch of Realm last week: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/1142

Building Realm from `master` should address the issue you're having. Realm v0.88.0 will be released shortly with this fix.

Comment: Thank you jpsim ! This is great news ! I was thinking that the behaviour of my code is a bit unexpected (...but this is sometimes quite normal ;)...). I look forward to Realm v0.88.0 !! Again - thank you very much for the quick answer !

Answer (score 0):

...hhm - seems that another method messed up !

The below code shows this method that loads data from a realm-file into a realm-wrapper-object.

Coming back to the original problem (location2/location2.realm file creating migraton-block):
Unfortunately, I was not aware that calling this "loadData_..."-method needed to be called with caution ! If it is called twice - once to location1/location1.realm and then a second time (to location2/location2.realm) - that is when things get messed up !

I tried to create a "wrapper" that loads and saves Realm-objects. But it seems more difficult with Realm than originally expected. Thanks for any comment on this !!

```
- (void) loadData_at_TopoNr_from_LocationRLM :(NSNumber *)TopoNr :(NSString *)folderName :(NSString *)fileName {

// realm-object calling "get_TopoResultRLM_FilePath" must be of same object-type, otherwise block-migration call !
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithPath:[self get_TopoResultRLM_FilePath :folderName :fileName]];

RLMResults *resTopoResult = [RLMTopoResult allObjectsInRealm:realm];
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TopoNrRLM == %d", [TopoNr intValue]];
RLMResults *resultTopoResult = [resTopoResult objectsWithPredicate:predicate1];

if ([resultTopoResult count] <= 1) {
    if ([resultTopoResult count] == 1) {
        // found one object
        // data loading
        self.TopoNrRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject TopoNrRLM];
        self.nameAnamneserRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject nameAnamneserRLM];
        self.anamneseDateRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject anamneseDateRLM];
        self.NumberOfCriteriaRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject NumberOfCriteriaRLM];
        self.BestMatchMethodRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject BestMatchMethodRLM];
        self.RealmFrameworkVersionRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject RealmFrameworkVersionRLM];
        self.BoundaryConditionVerionRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject BoundaryConditionVerionRLM];
        self.CriteriaRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject CriteriaRLM];
        self.imageNameRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject imageNameRLM];
        self.imageDataRLM = [resultTopoResult.firstObject imageDataRLM];
    }
    else { ....
```

Here is the property definition of the wrapper-object-class :

```
// GUIData-RLM
@property (nonatomic) RLMGUIData *GUIDataRLM;

// Location-RLM
@property (nonatomic) RLMTopoResult *LocationRLM;
```

Here is the object creation and call of that loadData_at...-method :

```
    RLMTopoResult *LocationRealm = [[RLMTopoResult alloc] init];
    [self setLocationRLM:LocationRealm];
    [LocationRealm loadData_at_TopoNr_from_LocationRLM :[NSNumber numberWithInt:[GUIDataRealm TopoNrRLM]] :[GUIDataRealm locationFolderNameRLM] :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%s", [GUIDataRealm locationFolderNameRLM], ".realm"]];
```